# Expo notifications android lightColor

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, push-notification, expo

I want to implement the notification feature using expo notifications, although everything works well I don't think my notification channel is working as intended. I'm saying this because I can't seem to get the light working(android notification light), does anyone know how to properly configure this feature?

```
  if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
    await Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync('default', {
      name: 'default',
      importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
      vibrationPattern: [0, 250, 250, 250],
      lightColor: '#FFFFFF',
    });
  }
```

This is exactly how I wrote my code, the reason I'm using the 'default' channel is so I can get it to work and then modify it.

I even tried specifying the notification channel on the notification like this, but I seem to be getting something wrong.

```
  await sendPushNotification({
                to: Users.filter(item => item !== undefined), // Doesn't work when array of tokens contains an undefined token
                sound: 'default',
                title: data.title,
                body: data.requester === 'none' ? "New post added! Check it out! " : "New post requested ✍️" ,

                data: data.requester !== 'none' ? { //This is to control user interaction to each notification
                    id: data.id,
                    type: 'New Request',
                    channelId: 'default'
                } : {
                    id: data.id,
                    type: 'New Post',
                    channelId: 'default'
                }
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

Well after a bit of debugging I finally found what my problem was.

The notification channel `setNotificationChannelAsync` returns or sets a channel that is structured like

```
 {
  "audioAttributes": null,
  "bypassDnd": false,
  "description": "",
  "enableLights": false,
  "enableVibrate": true,
  "groupId": null,
  "id": "",
  "importance": 6,
  "lightColor": "#FFFFFF",
  "lockscreenVisibility": 0,
  "name": "",
  "showBadge": true,
  "sound": "default",
  "vibrationPattern": Array [
    0,
    250,
    250,
    250,
  ],
}
```

All I needed to do was create a channel in this form because lights are set to false by default.

```
  if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
    await Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync('channelId', {
      importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
      enableLights: true,
      enableVibrate: true,
      lightColor: "#FFFFFF",
      name: "channelName",
      showBadge: true,
      sound: "default",
      vibrationPattern: Array [
    0,
    250,
    250,
    250,
  ],
    });
  }
```